# Using NSURLSession to play remote audio, code critique

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, nsurlsession

First, to avoid posting a great deal of code on here, I have created a very basic example of what I am after - https://github.com/opheliadesign/AudioTest.

I am brand new to iOS development and I'm having a little trouble understanding the best way to load and play a static MP3 file on a remote server. The audio is **not** streaming live, is less than a megabyte - about 30 seconds long in average (they are radio dispatches).

It has been suggested that I use NSURLSession to load the MP3 file and then play it within the completion block. This seems to be working but I have a feeling that I could be handling it better, just do not know how. Here is the block where I grab the audio and begin playing:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    NSLog(@"View loaded");
    // Register to receive notification from AppDelegate when entering background
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopPlayingAudio) name:@"stopPlayingAudio" object:nil];

    // Assign timer to update progress
    self.updateTimer =     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSeekBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    // Demo recording URL
    NSString *recordingUrl = @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/tevfd-recording/All_Fire_and_EMS_2015-02-0214_48_33_630819.mp3";

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recordingUrl] completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"No error..");
            self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithData:data error:nil];
            // Setup slider for track position
            self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
            self.slider.maximumValue = self.player.duration;
            [self.player prepareToPlay];
            [self.player play];
        }
    }]resume];

}
```

For example, have a slider that updates the player's position when it is moved. I initialize the AVAudioPlayer in the completion block but create a property for it in the header. If the player has not been initialized, could moving the slider cause a crash? If so, how should I handle this better?

Also, I have a timer that updates the slider position as the AVAudioPlayer plays. When the track reaches its end, the timer continues - clearly this is a potential memory issue. Not sure of the best way to handle this and I would also like for the user to be able to start playing the recording again after it is completed, for example if they moved the slider to the right.

I have searched and searched, cannot seem to find anything related to specifically what I am doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
This is what I first began with but I experienced some lag between clicking on a UITableView cell and presenting the view that loaded/played the audio. Several suggested NSURLSession.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Get the URL
    NSURL *callAudioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.call objectForKey:@"url"]];
    NSData *callAudioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:callAudioURL];
    AVAudioPlayer *audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData: callAudioData error:nil];
    self.player = audio;

    self.slider.minimumValue = 0;
    self.slider.maximumValue = self.player.duration;
    [[self player] play];
    self.updateTimer =     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateSeekBar) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to initialize the `AVAudioPlayer` with the remote URL directly? That seems like the simplest approach, save for just downloading and caching it and just then playing it from disk.

Comment: That's what I initially tried, and it was indeed the simplest approach, but it causes a slight lag between clicking on my UITableViewCell and presenting the player View. We're dealing with tiny files so maybe that isn't such a big deal.. just trying to do this the "right" way

Comment: @SevenBits please see update for my initial swing at this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're concerned about a small delay, then downloading and caching it *is* the best solution. You need to download the audio file and then play it locally. Typically playing -- or streaming -- from the network is useful only when the audio is so unique that you cannot store it locally.

To implement something like this (code untested):

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
NSFileHandle *hFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.localPath];
//did we succeed in opening the existing file?
if (!hFile) {   //nope->create that file!
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:self.localPath contents:nil attributes:nil];
   //try to open it again...
   hFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.localPath];
}
//did we finally get an accessable file?
if (!hFile) {
   NSLog("could not write to file %@", self.localPath); 
   return;
}

@try {
   //seek to the end of the file
   [hFile seekToEndOfFile];
   //finally write our data to it
   [hFile writeData:data];
} @catch (NSException * e) {
   NSLog("exception when writing to file %@", self.localPath); 
   result = NO;
}
   [hFile closeFile];
}
```

When all of the data has been received, start your audio:

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:self.localPath error:nil];
```

Comment: The average user of my app will be downloading several of these a day - I want to avoid filling up their device if possible..

Comment: Oh, and sorry to further explain. In my simple example it is a single audio file, in reality there will be many. Each is accessed by clicking on a Table View row and several are added daily

Comment: @NightMICU This would obviously depend on your app, but you could have an in/out queue of sorts -- once the user has downloaded an audio file, older ones are deleted to make room for the new. Then you can avoid taking up too much space while also saving on bandwidth.

Comment: Sounds like so much work just to play an audio file :( I had no problem with this in Android, not sure why it is such a struggle in iOS. I have found some libraries but they all seem to be for streaming live audio, not really what I am doing here.

Comment: This is looking like a good solution, I appreciate it. I'm guessing the best place to dump the file is something like ViewWillDisappear? Also, how would I go about deleting this file? Sorry, I'm only a week in to iOS and this is the only part of this app I'm struggling with.

Comment: appreciate the help, here's my attempt at your suggestion - https://gist.github.com/opheliadesign/617fe44eaeefdd704609. Hitting the "could not write to file" error. Took a stab at how to write the file based on another SO post, not sure if that code was correct.

Comment: An update based on this tutorial. Now simply taking the data returned by NSURLConnection and using that for the player, seems to be working great. http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

Comment: Accepted your answer because it got me on the right track, thanks! :)